# How do I pull page and click button with jquery?

Tags: jquery, iframe, click, buttonclick

I can access the page with an iframe and click the button. How do I do this with jquery? I want to pull the page with jquery and click the button. Can you help me.

Is there any other javascript method other than jquery alternative to iframe? If there is, it will happen.

Below is the code I made with the iframe. I want to do the same process in a different way. For example jquery.

```
function subToChannel(channelUrl) {
  var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.style.display = "none";
  iframe.src = channelUrl;
  iframe.onload = function() {
    console.log('Loaded iframe');
    setTimeout(function() {
      iframe.contentWindow.document.querySelector("#root > div > div.sc-AxjAm.tlQbp > div > main > div.root-scrollable.scrollable-area > div.simplebar-scroll-content > div > div > div.channel-root.channel-root--home.channel-root--unanimated > div.sc-AxjAm.fFlSEB > div.channel-root__info.channel-root__info--offline.channel-root__info--home > div > div.sc-AxjAm.kKCcYr.home-header-sticky > div.sc-AxjAm.gwJhkY > div.sc-AxjAm.QGSNR > div.ScTokenOverridesRegion-sc-15cvq8c-0.lfbUBX > div > div > div > div > div > div.sc-AxjAm.evhokJ > div > div > div > div > button").click();
      console.log('Subscribed to the channel: ' + channelUrl);
    }, 5000);
  }
  document.body.append(iframe);
  console.log('Added iframe to the page');
}

subToChannel('https://www.twitch.tv/fdghgffhgjhjhjgjh');
```

Comment: Why do you want to do it in a different way? This looks fine. The jQuery code will be very similar.

Comment: But unless your main page is in the `www.twitch.tv` domain, you can't do this. JavaScript can't access the contents of an iframe in a different domain.

Comment: The code I will run while on the twitch site. I want it to pull with jquery and click the button. Can you help?

Comment: can anyone help